# How to stop incrementing and decrimenting at the end of an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm a beginner in programming. I want to make an android app with 3 views.

1. text view (display text), and
2. buttons (FORWARD and BACK).

I made an array of words `one, two, three, four, five` to be displayed. 
I put `one` on the `xml`.

When the user clicks `FORWARD` it shows `two` when they click `FORWARD` again it shows `three` and when the user clicks `BACK` it shows `two`. I can do it until this poit.

The problem is when it reaches `five` and the user clicks `FORWARD` and when it reaches `one` and the user clicks `BACK` it crashes.

I want the button does nothing, not even goes back to `one`. I want the user to know that it is the end of the list. The same problem with `BACK` button. I want it stays on `one`. This is my code. please help.

```
public class aba extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i = 0;
    String[] myList = {
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_aba);

        }
        //Incrementing the value by l on forwardButton click
    public void forwardButton(View view) {
            TextView textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
            i = i + 1;
            textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
            if (i == myList.length) {
                i = i + 0;
            }
        }
        //decrementing the value by l on backButton click
    public void backButton(View view) {
        TextView textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
        i = i - 1;
        textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
        if (i == 0) {
            i = i - 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing of an array starts from 0.
Since your array contains 5 elements, the value of `length` is 5, but the indexing goes as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

This means you don't want to go below 0 and above 4.

(also, there is no reason to initialize your `TextView` on every button click)

Something like this should work:

```
int i = 0;
String[] myList={"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
TextView textDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aba);

    textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
}

public void forwardButton(View view)  {
    if(i < myList.length - 1) {
        i++;
        textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
    }

}

public void backButton(View view)  {
    if(i > 0) {
        i--;
        textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the check for the end of the array before you actually change the value of the index. Additionally, because Java indexes arrays from 0, you need to check for the index being one less than the length of the array.

```
//Incrementing the value by l on forwardButton click
public void forwardButton(View view)  {
    TextView textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay)

    if (i < myList.length - 1) {
        i=i+1;
    }

    textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
}
//decrementing the value by l on backButton click
public void backButton(View view)  {
    TextView textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);

    if(i > 0) {
        i=i-1;
    }

    textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
    if(i==0){
        i=i-0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set the text from an out-of-bounds array element is what is causing the crash, so you need to position your `if`s to make sure `i` is within the bounds of the `myList` array *before* trying to access it.

As it is, your `if` statements are not doing much to help. Aside from coming after the offending line of code, adding or subtracting 0 does not change the variable at all, so it wouldn't help.

```
//Incrementing the value by l on forwardButton click
public void forwardButton(View view) {
    TextView textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    i = i + 1;
    if (i >= myList.length) {
        // myList.length is past the end of the array, so set to length - 1
        i = myList.length - 1;
    }
    textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
}
//decrementing the value by l on backButton click
public void backButton(View view) {
    TextView textDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    i = i - 1;
    if (i < 0) {
        // -1 is before the beginning of the array, so set to 0 (beginning of the array)
        i = 0;
    }
    textDisplay.setText(myList[i]);
}
```

Comment: I much prefer the answers that show only changing the variable when it is valid to do so, but I'm keeping this here for the additional explanation it provides.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is, that in your if blocks you have `i=i+0` `i=i-0` which doesn't do anything (anything at all). It works the same as in math, `y=x-0` can be reduced to `y=x`. So the whole `if` statement is like it isnt there and you can delete it.

The second problem is, that (I think) you want to undo the this you did earlier `i=i+1` or`i=i-1`, but that is done and you can't "undo the instruction". Only thing you can do is do reverse operation, so in this case for `i=i-1` it would be `i=i+1`. BUT that woulden't change that you already loaded the text into the field and you would acces the array with index either -1 or lenght (which is one more than last index). So the solution would be to have your whole method body inside of you if statements and have the condition negated, so the incrementation and the change would only happen when you are inside the arrays bounds and not on the sides.

EDIT: Also you have to correct one condition. Arrays are indexed from 0 but the length is the count of "drawers" inside it. So when you try to get the `len-1`th element, you are accesing the last field in the array. so your condition should be `if(i==myList.length-1)` because then `i` is the last possible index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check only if the button you clicked has the right id :

```
public void forwardButton(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.forwardButton) {

    }
    }



            //decrementing the value by l on backButton click
        public void backButton(View view) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.backwardButton) {
     ...
    }}
```